# How to Use ContentValues and SQLiteOpenHelper to modify sqlite database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I wrote a rssFeedReader Application and use directly sqliteSyntax to modify database.
this is my code:

```
 database.execSQL database= openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

 database.execSQL("Create TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Press (press_name
 VARCHAR, press_url VARCHAR");

 database.execSQL("INSERT INTO Press VALUES ('Tasnim',
 'http://www.tasnimnews.com/english/rss/feed/?d=2&c=1&m=6&alt=Recent%20News');");

 database.execSQL("UPDATE Press press_name ='Tasnim',
 press_url ='http://www.tasnimnews.com/english/rss/feed/?
 d=2&c=1&m=6&alt=Recent%20News');");

 Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable", null);

 database.close();
```

and now my question is how can I migrate to **SQLiteOpenHelper** and **ConentValues** method to modify database.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Gets the data repository in write mode
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

// Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, id);
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CONTENT, content);

// Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
long newRowId;
newRowId = db.insert(
         FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
         FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE,
         values);
```

You can find it here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html